# Microsoft Graph API Mail: webLink for a deleted message?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to provide a `webLink` to the OWA for a deleted message. A regular message has a `webLink` property but once it's deleted, the URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<the_id>` returns that payload instead of the message information:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "x-x-x-x",
      "date": "2018-04-17T00:00:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Message is Deleted (or really what happens is the message is moved in the Mailbox to either the Deleted Items folder or one of the Retained-items folders) the Id of the Message changes so the error your getting back is consistent with that. This is why storing these Id's is mostly a bad idea because if messages are moved between folders etc the same thing will happen. What you will need to do is find the new Id for the Message based on its new location (which will depend on the Method used to delete the message) and you will need some type of Search parameter such as the InternetMessageId should work but a unique property like pidTagSearchKey would probably be better https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815908.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. But say if you had saved the Internet MessageId of the above message before it was either Soft or Hard deleted (meaning it would end up in the RecoverableItemsDeletions folder ) You could then using something like

```
GET /v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/messages/?$filter=internetMessageId+eq+%27%3c433353153.1229207532.1524008554985.JavaMail.root%40sjmas03.marketo.org%3e%27
```

to find the message in its new location